# What happens if i set realm=null instead of realm.close()

Tags: realm, realm-java

From the comment of `realm.isClosed()`

> - It's important to always remember to close Realm instances when you're   done with it in order not to leak memory, file descriptors or grow the size of Realm file out of measure.

So, what happens if i do not use `realm.close()` method but instead set  `realm=null`.

Comment: You'll probably prevent it from doing any cleanup, and you'll end up with the aforementioned resource leak.

Comment: And why would you want to do that to begin with? The API documentation is clear about calling `close()`.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing will happen, which is bad because it also means you won't free up native resources, which is **very bad** on background threads and can cause your Realm file size to explode.

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#large-realm-file-size